# SIGABRT when debugging Xamarin async method

Tags: c#, xamarin, async-await, visual-studio-mac, refit

I am trying to figure out why this code is crashing on debug mode with Visual Studio for Mac.

It runs OK if no breakpoints are set, but when stepping-in, application crashes with the following error message:

```
2017-10-23 10:26:11.137 Refit20171023[50460:17803570] error: * Assertion at /Users/builder/data/lanes/5481/2f8bbec0/source/xamarin-macios/external/mono/mono/mini/debugger-agent.c:4714, condition `array->len == 1' not met
[...]
Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates...
```

Application crashes on "this.username = user.Login;" line.

```
    public async override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        var gh = RestService.For<IGitHubApi>("https://api.github.com");
        var user = await gh.GetUser("octocat");
        txtUsername.Text = user.Login;
    }
```

It crashes when assigning user.Login to txtUsername.Text or to a variable string. 
This is the full .cs file

```
using System;
using UIKit;
using Refit;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace mySampleApp
{
    public class User
    {
        public string Login { get; set; }
    }

    [Headers("User-Agent: Refit Integration Tests")]
    public interface IGitHubApi
    {
        [Get("/users/{username}")]
        Task<User> GetUser(string userName);
    }

    public partial class ViewController : UIViewController
    {
        string username;

        protected ViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
        {
        }

        public async override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();

            var gh = RestService.For<IGitHubApi>("https://api.github.com");
            var user = await gh.GetUser("octocat");
            this.username = user.Login;
        }


        public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
        {
            base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();
        }
    }
}
```

However, crash doesn't happen if, instead, I assign user.Login trough a property.

This code runs and debugs OK.

```
using System;
using UIKit;
using Refit;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace mySampleApp
{
    public class User
    {
        public string Login { get; set; }
    }

    [Headers("User-Agent: Refit Integration Tests")]
    public interface IGitHubApi
    {
        [Get("/users/{username}")]
        Task<User> GetUser(string userName);
    }

    public partial class ViewController : UIViewController
    {
        string username;

        public string pUsername
        {
            get { return username; }
            set {
                username = value;
                // UITextField txtUsername
                txtUsername.Text = value;
            }
        }

        protected ViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
        {
        }

        public async override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();

            var gh = RestService.For<IGitHubApi>("https://api.github.com");
            var user = await gh.GetUser("octocat");
            this.pUsername = user.Login;
        }


        public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
        {
            base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();
        }
    }
}
```

Any reason on why this is behaving this way?

Comment: Maybe related to this thread somewhere else, although it was left unanswered https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/96564/sigabrt-while-debugging-async-methods/p1

Comment: I found somewhat a solution https://mindofai.github.io/Workaround-for-Xamarin.Forms'-DisplayAlert-Bug-(Alert-Being-Shown-Twice)/ the general problem is you cant modify UI from a thread that is not the main thread.